# Can we generate data from two exponential distributions with correlation -1

Tags: distribution, correlation, probability-density, pearson, exponential-distribution

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66775/attainable-correlations-for-exponential-random-variables

With reference to the above link I want to ask if it is impossible to generate two exponential distributions with correlation -1 ?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, it is impossible to generate two exponentials with a correlation of -1.  Basically, this is because of the asymmetry around the mean.